# How to fix this error on a python pizza program

Tags: python

I made a program where you can choose what size pizza you want, the topping and than it will show you the price of everything. Most of it works fine until you get to the receipt part, where it keeps showing me an error about integers and strings. Can someone please help me, any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks,
Drizzy

```
pizza_size = []
pizza_topping = []
pizza_size_price = []

pizza_size_input = input("What size of pizza do you want?\nSmall: 7.99$\nMedium: 9.99$\nLarge: 11.99\nEnter your desired pizza size: ")
pizza_size.append(pizza_size_input)
prompt = "\nPlease enter your desired topping for your pizza (.5$ per topping): "
prompt += "\n(Enter 'quit' when you are finished choosing your topics)"

if pizza_size == 'small':
    pizza_size_price.append('7.99')
elif pizza_size == 'medium':
    pizza_size_price.append('9.99')
elif pizza_size == 'large':
    pizza_size_price.append('11.99')


def loops():
    for pizza_topping in pizza_topping:
        print(pizza_topping + " = 50 cents")

def reciept():
        print("Sorry, thats not a valid pizza size.")
        print("Pizza Size: " + pizza_size_input)          
        print("Topping: " + loops)
        print("Subtotal: " + subtotal)
        print("Total: " + total)

while True:
    topping = input(prompt)
    pizza_topping.append(topping)
    print(len(pizza_topping))
    if topping == 'quit':
        extra_quit_that_is_not_needed = 'quit'
        pizza_topping.remove(extra_quit_that_is_not_needed)
        toppingss = len(pizza_topping)
        print("There are " + str(toppingss) + " toppings on your pizza")
        topping_price = len(pizza_topping) * 0.5
        print(loops)
        print(reciept)
        break
    else:
        print("I love " + topping.title() + "!")


subtotal = len(str(pizza_topping)) * 50 + (pizza_size_price)
total = subtotal * 0.13
```

The end of the program shows the err0r

Comment: What's the exact error with trace?

Comment: Can you please add the error, expected output, and output you are getting in your post

Comment: There's a lot wrong with this code. Even once the error you mentioned is fixed, you're going to run into other problems. You're going to need to debug this and narrow it down to a specific problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this as full code:

```
pizza_size = []
pizza_topping = []
pizza_size_price = []

pizza_size_input = input("What size of pizza do you want?\nSmall: 7.99$\nMedium: 9.99$\nLarge: 11.99\nEnter your desired pizza size: ")
pizza_size.append(pizza_size_input)
prompt = "\nPlease enter your desired topping for your pizza (.5$ per topping): "
prompt += "\n(Enter 'quit' when you are finished choosing your topics)"

if pizza_size == 'small':
    pizza_size_price.append('7.99')
elif pizza_size == 'medium':
    pizza_size_price.append('9.99')
elif pizza_size == 'large':
    pizza_size_price.append('11.99')
while True:
    topping = input(prompt)
    pizza_topping.append(topping)
    print(len(pizza_topping))
    if topping == 'quit':
        extra_quit_that_is_not_needed = 'quit'
        pizza_topping.remove(extra_quit_that_is_not_needed)
        toppingss = len(pizza_topping)
        print("There are " + str(toppingss) + " toppings on your pizza")
        topping_price = len(pizza_topping) * 0.5
        for pizza_topping_ in pizza_topping:
            print(pizza_topping_ + " = 50 cents")
        print("Pizza Size: " + pizza_size_input)          
        print("Topping: " + ', '.join(pizza_topping))
        subtotal = len(pizza_topping) * 50 + int(next(iter(pizza_size_price),0))
        total = subtotal * 0.13
        print("Subtotal: " + str(subtotal))
        print("Total: " + str(total))       
        break
    else:
        print("I love " + topping.title() + "!")
```

Lots of stuff been replaced.

Example Output:

```
What size of pizza do you want?
Small: 7.99$
Medium: 9.99$
Large: 11.99
Enter your desired pizza size: large

Please enter your desired topping for your pizza (.5$ per topping): 
(Enter 'quit' when you are finished choosing your topics)Honey
1
I love Honey!

Please enter your desired topping for your pizza (.5$ per topping): 
(Enter 'quit' when you are finished choosing your topics)Ham
2
I love Ham!

Please enter your desired topping for your pizza (.5$ per topping): 
(Enter 'quit' when you are finished choosing your topics)Bacon
3
I love Bacon!

Please enter your desired topping for your pizza (.5$ per topping): 
(Enter 'quit' when you are finished choosing your topics)Pineapple
4
I love Pineapple!

Please enter your desired topping for your pizza (.5$ per topping): 
(Enter 'quit' when you are finished choosing your topics)Cheese
5
I love Cheese!

Please enter your desired topping for your pizza (.5$ per topping): 
(Enter 'quit' when you are finished choosing your topics)quit
6
There are 5 toppings on your pizza
Honey = 50 cents
Ham = 50 cents
Bacon = 50 cents
Pineapple = 50 cents
Cheese = 50 cents
Pizza Size: large
Topping: Honey, Ham, Bacon, Pineapple, Cheese
Subtotal: 250
Total: 32.5
```

I removed some functions to remove errors and changed some types, basically that's all.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your problem comes by trying to add ints to strings. If you want to concatenate a number to a string make sure to cast it to a string first like so:

```
print("Total: " + str(total))
```

Now you have a string version of your integer ( or float) which you can concatenate with a string.

Comment: That's not all.

Comment: Well, one of the problems ;)